# Return statement before a catch statement

Tags: java, android, return

I've added a return statement to my AsncTask and yet I still get an error telling me to add one. The only snippet of code that stops this Syntax error is adding a return statement after the catch statement, but that's counter productive and doesn't address the needs of the program and I can't access the Strings I need to ( I need to check if the return OuputStream is equal to true.

Code:

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... userandpass)  { //I still get an error telling me to add a return statement
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:1337");
            HttpURLConnection URLconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            URLconnection.setDoOutput(true);
            URLconnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            //output stream
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(URLconnection.getOutputStream());
            writestream(out, userandpass);

            //buffered server response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(URLconnection.getInputStream());
            String result = readstream(in);
            Log.e(result, result);

            // check we haven't been redirected (Hotel Wifi, for example).
            checkrediect(URLconnection, url);

            Boolean result_true = checkresult(result);

            if(result_true) {
                return true;  
            } else {
                return false;
            }



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: From first look I would say, the second catch-block is the execution path missing a return statement.

Comment: remove that redundant check on `result_true` and add `return result_true;` at the end of method thats all you need

Comment: `if(result_true)return true;else return false;` does the same as `return result_true`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but that's counter productive and doesn't address the needs of the program

Well what are the "needs of the program"? What do you *want* the result to be if an `IOException` is thrown? It must be true, false, or an exception - at the moment, it's none of those.

I'd recommend that *most* of the time, you just let exceptions bubble up... can you actually proceed as if nothing had gone wrong in the case of an `IOException`?

As a side-note, this is ugly:

```
if(result_true) {
    return true;  
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Just use:

```
return checkresult(result);
```

(And ideally rename various methods and variables to follow Java naming conventions.)

I'd also suggest changing it to return `boolean` rather than `Booelean`.

Comment: I know that if IOException is called the function must be false, but how would I check for the string to be true?

Comment: why not assign the appropriate value to result_true within those catch blocks and just return the result_true at the end of the method?

Comment: @srikanthyaradla So, I check for the result and then add a return statement after the catch block?

Comment: yes you declare that variable result at the beginning of the method with some default value and assign the value wherever appropriate and return at the end of method

Comment: @TheBlueCat: If an IOException means you should return false, you can just return that from the catch block, if you *really* want to...

Answer (score 6):

You have a branch of your catch statement that neither returns a value nor throws an exception.

```
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That block there needs to have some form of code that will return something, otherwise the method will not be able to function properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `return` statement with in the `method block`.

Do it like this....

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... userandpass)  { 

boolean isOk = false;

// Your code

if(result_true) {
                isOk = true;

            } else {

                isOk = false;
            }

 return isOk;

 }
```

Comment: returning the boolean variable result_true from within the if-else block wont be considered a return from the method... so i am setting another variable isOk to be returned outside the block

Answer (score 0):

You must had a return statement in the `catch (IOException e)` block.  The compiler cannot know what to return when you catch the IOException.

You have 2 choices, return something (false), or rethrow the exception.